# Different types of property bindings in angular2?

Tags: angular

I've started learning Angular 2 Beta version. Angular 2 provides different types of property bindings like **{{title}}** and **[src]** and **bind-src**.

I know that property bindings binds the data to element and extends its behavior, but Could any one tell me about why there are three types if one type like **[src]** could do the job for us when we need binding. If i am wrong then where we will use the other types ?

Answer (score 4):

Interpolation binding `{{template expression}}` always converts the result of the template expression to a string, and it is normally used to bind to the DOM `textContent` property.

Property binding `[someProperty]="template expression"` does not convert the result to a string, so it is useful when you want to bind an array or an object to a child input property, for example.

`bind-src` is just the *[canonical form](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-target)* of `[src]` binding.

Answer (score 1):

Property binding can be defined either by wrapping the attribute in [brackets] or by prefixing bind- with the attribute name. Property binding allows us to send logic from the component class, to the view.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `

<h1>My First Angular App</h1>

<img [src]="imageUrl">
<img bind-src="imageUrl">

})

export class AppComponent { 

imageUrl = 'https://angular.io/resources/images/logos/angular2/angular.png';

}
```